# Фильтр в WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Мне нужно чтобы работало некоторое количество фильтров, я сдела два фильтра но работает один, как сделать чтобы работало два

```
        public List<DataText> ListDataText = new List<DataText>();

    public List<MyCheckBox> TempList = new List<MyCheckBox>();

    public ListCollectionView View { get; set; }

    public TextViewModel()
    {
        MyProperty = new List<MyCheckBox>();


        View = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ListDataText);
        View.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("TimeData", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        View.Filter = new Predicate<object>(Filter);// o => _txtSearch == null || ((string)o).Contains(_txtSearch);
      //  View.Filter = new Predicate<object>(FilterDat);
    }

    private bool Filter(object obj)
    {
        var data = obj as DataText;
        if (data != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_txtSearch))
            {
                return data.Discription.Contains(_txtSearch);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private bool FilterDat(object item)
    {
        DateTime fromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(FromDate);
        DateTime toDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ToDate);

        DataText item12 = (DataText)item;

        var rt = item12.TimeData.Split(',');
        DateTime tim = Convert.ToDateTime(rt[0]);

        return (fromDate <= tim && toDate >= tim);

    }
 string fr;
    public string FromDate
    {
        get { return fr; }
        set
        {
            fr = value;
            OnPropertyChange("FromDate");
            View.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private string todat;
    public string ToDate
    {
        get { return todat; }
        set
        {
            todat = value;
            OnPropertyChange("ToDate");
            View.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private string _txtSearch;
    public string TxtSearch
    {
        get { return _txtSearch; }
        set
        {
            _txtSearch = value;
            OnPropertyChange("TxtSearch");
           // View.Filter = new Predicate<object>(Filter);
            View.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

xaml

```
 <dxg:GridControl EnableSmartColumnsGeneration="True" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding View}" 
                     x:Name="myGridControl"  
                     Margin="0,0,3,0"  
                     SelectionMode="Row" Grid.RowSpan="5">

        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Type" FieldName="TypeFiles" Width="30"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Time Data"  FieldName="TimeData" SortMode="DisplayText" SortOrder="Ascending" Width="50"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Classa"     FieldName="DataClasa" Width="60"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Co to jest"  FieldName="Discription" />
        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>

        <dxg:GridControl.TotalSummary>
            <dxg:GridSummaryItem FieldName="TimeData" SummaryType="Count"/>
            <dxg:GridSummaryItem SummaryType="Count" Alignment="Right"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.TotalSummary>

        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView AllowPerPixelScrolling="True" 
                           ShowFixedTotalSummary="True" 
                           UseEvenRowBackground="True" 
                           AllowEditing="False" 
                           NavigationStyle="Row" AutoWidth="True"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>
```

Что я сделал не так ? Как это исправить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы для фильтра указываете только один метод. А нужно, чтобы отработали оба:

```
View.Filter = o => Filter(o) && FilterDat(o);
```